# simplify a loop in python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I am using this loop in my python code:

```
final_fun=[]
for i_base in xrange(n_base):
  final_fun.append(sum(fun[:,i_base])/n_ci)
```

and I would want to know how I can simplify this loop? If I simplify this loop will my program be faster? In general I know how to simplify this but here I am blocked by the append!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use list comprehensions. It's faster and cleaner. The interpreter can be slowed down a lot by the for loop, and there's nothing to lose by simply rearranging the syntax.

See [this explanation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops) for more details.

```
final_fun = [sum(fun[:,i_base])/n_ci for i_base in xrange(n_base)]
```

Comment: This *can* get complicated sometimes its just nice to have a for loop

Comment: for loops are often slower in python. Especially if you are using multiple for loops, list comprehensions are designed to handle this kind of thing more efficiently.

Comment: thank you! I tried this at the beginning but with some mistakes!

Comment: @RobVolgman they might be slow, but when i open up a module that contains nothing but list comprehensions in every line even nested list comprehensions it makes me want to stab a fool

Answer (score 2):

It seems `fun` is a two-dimensional NumPy array.  In this case, you can simplify and speed up the code significantly by completely avoiding the Python loop:

```
final_fun = fun.sum(axis=0) / n_ci
```

You will end up with a NumPy array instead of a list, but chances are this is what you want anyway.

Comment: +1.  Thank you for being attentive to an already answered question.